# Set focus on textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

In a textbox user can enter date. In OnChange event I am trying to validate the date using javascript, if it is not a valid date  showing an alert message and setting the focus on the textbox.

Here when I enter invalid date and press tab, the onchange events fires , in case of invalid date it does not set focus on the texbox, instead the focus is set on next textbox in the form.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateOfBirth" runat="server"
    onchange="validateDate(this)"></asp:TextBox>

function validateDate(sender) {
    if (!Date.parseInvariant(sender.value, "MM/dd/yyyy")) {
        alert("date is incorrect");
        sender.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to solve this with a little debugging...

Comment: sender.focus() and  $(sender).focus()  are same.

Comment: What's likely happening is that the tab keypress event is being processed after the `onchange` event, so the focus is indeed set to the textbox, but it was already there, and then the keypress event occurs moving focus to the next textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `onblur` instead of `onchange`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    check = function (sender) {
        if (sender) {
            alert("check");             
            sender.focus();
        }
    }
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" onblur="check(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

In the above example, focus is returned to the input as expected.

Comment: Thanks James!!! 
meanwhile I found a workaround , set focus on some other control and then set focus on the current control.
e.g  $(input).focus();  sender.focus();
It worked for me.