# Give textbox focus in popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a button that when clicked results in a modal popup:

```
protected void addHoursButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    var addHoursPopup = btn.FindControl("addHoursPopup") as ModalPopupExtender;
    addHoursPopup.Show();
}
```

It works fine but I am trying to add focus to the top textbox in it:

```
protected void addHoursButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    var addHoursPopup = btn.FindControl("addHoursPopup") as ModalPopupExtender;
    addHoursPopup.Show();

    var addHoursInput = btn.FindControl("addHoursInput") as TextBox;
    addHoursInput.Focus();
}
```

I have tried placing the focus call before and after the popup to no avail. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: why dont you try to do that in javascript, after click ?

Comment: Where *is* the focus when your page loads after this call?  Perhaps you have some other code (server or client side) that is setting the focus elswhere after this call.  Your code looks like it should work to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To focus a TextBox when a Windows Form first loads, simply set the TabIndex for the TextBox to zero (or the lowest TabIndex for any Control on the Form).
>
> When a Form is displayed, it automatically focuses the Control with the lowest TabIndex.  Note that if your TextBox is pre-initialized with some text, then the entire Text will be selected.

Source: http://www.csharp411.com/c-focus-textbox-on-form-load/

---

Something else I've found:

```
textBox.Select();
textBox.Focus();
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686836/focus-on-textbox-does-not-work

---

You can use the JavaScript code below, it does need some tweaking to fit your needs.
You'll probably need an onload in the body and send the ID of the textbox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    check = function (sender) {
        if (sender) {
            alert("check");             
            sender.focus();
        }
    }
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" onblur="check(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

But what intrested me more, was the comment on the solution:

> meanwhile I found a workaround , set focus on some other control and then set focus on the current control. e.g $(input).focus(); sender.focus();
>   It worked for me

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910968/set-focus-on-textbox-using-javascript

---

Last thing that might help you: http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Focus-ASP.NET.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I am using asp.net and Select is not a valid call.

Comment: @DavidTunnell I added some more (possible) solutions

Answer (score 1):

You can register a call to javascript from the codebehind to set focus.  Put this code in your OnClick method:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "focus", 
"document.getElementById('" + this.addHoursInput.ClientID + "').focus();", true);
```

Comment: I am getting the same result, no focus for some reason =\

Comment: what browser and version?  Have you tried looking at the console in the dev tools in your browser to see if it's generating an error?